# Calling a JavaScript function from a .js file in Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, function

I was trying to call a function from a .js file in the Google App Engine enviroment.

the code of the html print goes like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class jumpPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        self.response.out.write('');
        self.response.out.write('');
        self.response.out.write('<head>');
        self.response.out.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/pxc11.js" >');
        self.response.out.write('</script>');
        self.response.out.write('</head>');
        self.response.out.write('<body">');
        self.response.out.write('<form name="f1">');
        self.response.out.write('  <input type="hidden" name="theStartValue" value="1"><p>');
        self.response.out.write('  <input type="button" value="-15" onClick="dummy()">');
        self.response.out.write('  <input type="button" value="+15" onClick="dummy()" ><p>');
        self.response.out.write('</form>');
        self.response.out.write('</body>');
        self.response.out.write('');
        self.response.out.write('</html>');


application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/tonteria', jumpPage)],
                                     debug=True)


def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and then the .js is just this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text⁄javascript">
function dummy()
{
    alert("POPOPOPOPOPO");
}
<⁄script>
```

The app.yaml includes a static folder that has the .js file.

```
    handlers:
    - url: /js
      static_dir: js
    - url: /tonteria
      script: tonteria.py
```

Comment: Yes, and what happens? Be specific.

Comment: I'm sorry, what happened was that the HTML was showing and I could see and click the buttons but the Javascript functions weren't triggered. I was putting these HTML tags in the .js code...

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of editing headache by using templates.

Answer (score 4):

`.js` files contain *Javascript*, not HTML tags.

Comment: mmmm omg maybe that's the error, feel kind of ridiculous!
Ok it works now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your life might be easier by making the file into an html template and then rendering it with your variables.  Google has a great [tutorial](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates.html)